# RxJava filter behaviour

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2, rx-binding

I wrote code which is debouncing text in `EditText` and filtering out text with lest than 4 characters:

```
charSequenceInitialValueObservable.skipInitialValue()
    .filter(new Predicate<CharSequence>() {
      @Override public boolean test(@NonNull CharSequence charSequence) throws Exception {
        Log.d("TAG", "l: " + charSequence.length());
        return charSequence.length() > 3;
      }
    })
    .doOnNext(new Consumer<CharSequence>() {
      @Override public void accept(@NonNull CharSequence charSequence) throws Exception {
        Log.d("TAG", "1. doOnNext: \"" + charSequence + "\"");
      }
    })
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnNext(new Consumer<CharSequence>() {
      @Override public void accept(@NonNull CharSequence charSequence) throws Exception {
        Log.d("TAG", "2. doOnNext: \"" + charSequence + "\"");
      }
    })
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<CharSequence>() {
      @Override
      public void onNext(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull CharSequence charSequence) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onNext: \"" + charSequence + "\"");
      }

      @Override public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onError: " + e.toString());
      }

      @Override public void onComplete() {
        Log.d("TAG", "onComplete");
      }
    });
```

When user is entering text - filtering works fine, but when user is using backspace, last empty char sequence is delivered to `Subscriber`:

```
1. doOnNext: "test hhu"
l: 7
1. doOnNext: "test hh"
l: 6
1. doOnNext: "test h"
l: 5
1. doOnNext: "test "
l: 4
1. doOnNext: "test"
l: 3
l: 2
l: 1
l: 0
2. doOnNext: ""
onNext: ""
```

Is this expected behaviour? Should I use filter operator second time after debounce? How to filter out it properly?

Comment: On Android, the CharSequence you are receiving is a mutable one so it may change when evaluated after the debounce. You should map it into an immutable String via toString early on and work with that.

Comment: @akarnokd That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debounce passes through the last value after no value is passed for the given timeout, so in theory it should be passing through `"test"`.
However the only value that gets through is `""` which probably indicates that the value is not immutable and gets overwritten before it passes through the debounce operator.

To fix this, make sure that `charSequenceInitialValueObservable` only receives immutable values or make a defensive copy before the `debounce`. (Something like `.map(cs -> new String(cs))`)